# how to count distinct value per day with start time and end time

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-5.7, count, date

my title may seem a bit confusing but here's the context.

I have a table 1. It contains the reference code per connection to SSID with value of start time. Now I have a scenario wherein the user connects today and disconnects after 2days. So in the table it only has 1 record containing starttime which is today and endtime that contains 2days after today.

Now I want to extract a report of user connection per day. In this case when I group by on the reference code per day, it will only count as 1 for 3 days. but i want it to be counted as 1 per day. What are some ways that I can do this?

[image: the row marked as x is the one I am describing above.]

@MrBrownstone
The result of that query would be

```
username                 starttime         count(*)
445425760933             2019-02-05            1
445425760934             2019-02-05            1
445425760934             2019-02-06            1
```

This is not the result that I am looking for. Below is the result that I need:

```
username                 starttime         count(*)
445425760933             2019-02-05            1
445425760933             2019-02-06            1
445425760933             2019-02-07            1
445425760934             2019-02-05            1
445425760934             2019-02-06            1
```

Since the code 445425760933 was used until 2019-02-07

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL 8+:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS (
SELECT MIN(DATE(starttime)) `date` 
  FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT `date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
  FROM dates 
  WHERE `date` < ( SELECT MAX(DATE(endtime)) 
                   FROM table1 )
),
users AS (
SELECT DISTINCT username 
  FROM table1
)
SELECT /* DISTINCT */ users.username, dates.`date`, 1 `count(*)`
FROM users
JOIN dates
JOIN table1 ON table1.username = users.username
           AND dates.`date` BETWEEN DATE(table1.starttime) 
                                AND DATE(table1.endtime)
```

Comment: sorry I did not mention the version im using. its mysql 5.7

Comment: For 5.7 you can move pseudotables from WITH clause to FROM clause. The recursive CTE can be converted using statically-generated numbers list. Or you can try to use a variable, of course, but this technique sometimes can give unpredictably strange result while applying in subquery - I do not recommend this.

Comment: @DriggsAlonzo Is there any maximum possible difference between `starttime` and `endtime` (counting in days)? Some days count which guarantee the difference will never be longer?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your needs correctly, you could use the `DATE` function to group by just the date and ignore the time:

```
SELECT username, DATE(starttime) AS start_date, COUNT(*) as `count`
  FROM my_table
GROUP BY username, DATE(starttime)
ORDER BY username, DATE(starttime);
```

You can find more information regarding date and time functions below:

[Date and Time Functions (MySQL Reference)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

**EDIT**

Based on the additional information provided you will need an ancillary table that contains just dates in order to achieve what you want to do:

```
CREATE TABLE `dates`
(
    `Date` DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

SELECT DISTINCT username, `Date`, COUNT(*) as `count`
  FROM my_table AS t
  JOIN dates AS d
    ON d.`Date` BETWEEN DATE(t.startime) AND DATE(t.endtime)
 GROUP BY username, `Date`
 ORDER BY username, `Date`;
```